# SQL - store a query as a local variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

So I need to do a query based on the results of another query. 
Is there a way for me to set the result of a query to a variable so I can use the result of that in another query?

Example:
{original query} --->

```
SELECT
tablea.number

FROM tablea

INNER JOIN tableb

ON tablea.name = tableb.name

WHERE tableb.zip = '11111'
```

Now I want to use this result to then do another query:

```
SELECT *

FROM tablea

WHERE number = (results of last query)
```

I think theres a way to set the first query to a variable so that that way the second one can just use the result, just not sure how. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM tableb WHERE zip = '11111')
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM tablea A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableb 
              WHERE zip = '11111'
              AND name = A.name)
```

Comment: Thanks! Ive been trying to figure out the easiest way to do this. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can select directly into a variable:

```
declare @number int

select @number = tablea.number
from ...etc...

select *
from tablea
where number = @number
```

There are a few other ways of doing the same thing, but this is how you'd do it with a variable.